# Deprecated классы http

Tags: android

Добрый день. Занимаюсь переписыванием на Xamarin сильно устаревшего приложения Андроид, Java, и столкнулся с необходимостью переписать код с 4 официально deprecated классов. Код примерно следующий, запрос именно POST, с post отправляется именно картинка. url и filepath в данном случае строки, их конкретное содержание неважно.

```
DefaultHttpClient h = new DefaultHttpClient();
HttpPost p = new HttpPost(url);
Java.IO.File f = new Java.IO.File(filepath);
FileEntity e = new FileEntity(f, "image/png");
p.Entity = e;
IHttpResponse p1 = h.Execute(p);
var s = EntityUtils.ToString(p1.Entity);
```

Буду благодарен, если кто подскажет, как это адекватно переписать, с HttpUrlConnection или вроде того. Пока что всё, что добился, это ответа bad request.

Comment: смотрите в сторону OkHttp. если будете работать чисто с рестом то ретрофит.

Comment: @SviatVolkov хорошо бы оформить ответом с примерами. Тема актуальная.

Comment: @rjhdby не буду оформлять ответом, т.к. не знаю что там в xamarin'e происходит. мб есть какие-то ксамариновские решения

Answer (score 0):

```
try{
    URL url = new URL("http(s)://blabla.com");
    Http(s)URLConnection huc = (Http(s)URLConnection) url.openConnection();
    huc.setDoOutput(true);
    huc.setDoInput(true);
    BufferedWriter bw = new BufferedWriter(new OutputStreamWriter(huc.getinputStream()));
    huc.addRequestProperty("Content-Type", "multipart/form-data; boundary=---------------------------74482520013458"); //Некоторый номер
    huc.addRequestProperty("Content-Length", "длина картинки");

    File file = new File("filename.png");
    FileInputStream fis = new FileInputStream(file);
    StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
    int ch = 0;
    while(fis.available()>0){
         sb.append((char)ch);
    }
    fis.close();
    bw.write("-----------------------------74482520013458\r\n");//Номер должен совпазать с номером из Content-Type
    bw.write("Content-Disposition: form-data; name=\"data\" filename=\"filename.png\r\n\"");
    bw.write("Content-Type: image/png\r\n\r\n");
    bw.write(sb.toString());
    bw.write("-----------------------------74482520013458--\r\n"); //Завершающая строка
    bw.flush();

    BufferedReader br = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(huc.getInputStream()));

    sb = new StringBuilder();
    while(br.ready()){
      sb.append(br.readLine());
    }

    br.close();
    bw.close();

}catch(Exception e){
   e.printStackTrace();
}
```

Примерно так.

Comment: В ответе используется Java, вопрос о том, как переписать на Xamarin (C#)

Comment: Да, в Ксамарине получается практически такой же код, только, понятно, все методы с большой буквы, кроме того, вместо setDoOutput(true) будет DoOutput = true, и вместо huc.getinputStream() будет huc.InputStream.

Comment: Но - этот код пока что не работает. Во-первых, вместо ch=0 должно быть, очевидно, ch=fis.Read(). В том виде, в каком оно сейчас, бесконечно пишутся нули.

Comment: Во-вторых, BufferedWriter bw = new BufferedWriter(new OutputStreamWriter(huc.getinputStream())) в том месте, в каком он написан сейчас, выдаёт exception Java.IO.FileNotFoundException. Если переместить команду после AddRequestProperty, exception "content-length promised ....bytes, but received 0". Deprecated код, написанный выше, получал ответ.

Comment: Да, ещё вопрос с длиной картинки в хидере (addRequestProperty). Имея файл, я могу, понятно, посмотреть его длину file.Length(). Но, по идее, к этой величине надо добавить длину служебной информации, которая далее в коде пишется в поток? (bw.write(....) )